# How to set a custom font for android application?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I can't seem to be able to change the standard android font to another in my application. I'm writing my app in Kotlin and I'm using Anko to lay it out. I've tried:

```
typeface = Typeface.create()
typeface = Typface.createFromAsset(assets, "font/font_name")
setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "font/font_name"))
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're missing the file extension. On top of that Typeface.create doesn't support caching, so it's wasteful if repeated. Use a library: https://github.com/Drivemode/TypefaceHelper, https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for that!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem on Android Studio 3.1 Canary with Kotlin

Here is the solution: for **font/lobster_regular.ttf** file

```
var typeFace: Typeface? = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this.applicationContext, R.font.lobster_regular)
```

**Example:**

[image]

```
private var _customFontTextView: TextView? = null
private var _typeFace:           Typeface? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    this._initializeResources()
    this._initializeGUI()
}

private fun _initializeResources() {
    this._customFontTextView = this.findViewById(R.id.custom_font_text_view)
    this._typeFace           = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this.applicationContext, R.font.lobster_regular)
}

private fun _initializeGUI() {
    this._customFontTextView!!.setTypeface(this._typeFace, Typeface.NORMAL)
}
```

Also you can do more with downloadable fonts, here is the article from Google: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts.html

Comment: how would I specify a font size for the variable?

Comment: I have set font on textview here and I am sure you know how to set font size on textview, right?

Comment: I mean is there one method that we can declare the font type and size?

Answer (score 3):

Try this, from [this tutorial from SEGUN](https://segunfamisa.com/posts/custom-fonts-with-android-support-library):

```
val myCustomFont : Typeface? = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.my_font)
myView.typeface = myCustomFont
```

**Note:** you'll need to have the `.ttf` font downloaded in your project to do so - not just the `.xml` for the downloadable font.

Answer (score 3):

**this is a great and short way for do it :**
1- create a folder named **`font`** in the **`res`** folder.
2- then put your font file in the **`font`** folder that you created. (we suppose your font file name is **`sample_font.ttf`**)
3- so now create a **xml** file in the font folder named **`sample.xml`** and put the following code in it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <font
        android:font="@font/sample_font"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="500" />
</font-family>
```

4- now go to and open the **`res/values/styles.xml`** and then add following line code to the main style (common name  is **`AppTheme`**)

```
<item name="fontFamily">@font/sample</item>  //put name of xml file in the font folder
```

now run the your app and you'll see your application font changed.

Answer (score 2):

We can create class for custom textView. for example we need textview with roboto font

```
class RobotoTextView(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : AppCompatTextView(context, attrs) {
    init {
        val typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().assets, "font/roboto.ttf")
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ||
                android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
            setTypeface(typeface)
        }
    }
}
```

then we can use it on every xml layout

```
<com.packagename.RobotoTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World"/>
```

Comment: When we are using a Custom font in a lot of places. This is the best way to do it !

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one, from my working code ( In Kotlin )

if you are in some other Class file, then use this one

```
var typeFaceBold: Typeface? =
    this.getApplicationContext()?.let { ResourcesCompat.getFont(it, R.font.sans_serif_bold) }
    tvAnonymousText.typeface = typeFaceBold
```

If you are using it in Activity, then you can write like this

```
var typeFaceBold: Typeface? = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this.applicationContext, R.font.sans_serif_bold) }
tvAnonymousText.typeface = typeFaceBold
```